# Google Cloud Storage doesn't work with Google Apps?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to use the Google Cloud Storage API which is published now under the Docs section of the App Engine site. The documentation states you have to add the appengine service account as a team member in the API-console.
However, we're using Cloud Storage within a Google Apps domain, which only allows users from that domain to be added as team members. So, isn't possible  add the service account (which is@appspot.gserviceaccount.com) ?. Is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [GSUtil](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) to add the service account to the ACL of the bucket.
See my related [answer on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450117/allowing-publicly-shared-files-on-google-cloud-storage/9451195#9451195).

Comment: @mihai Doesn't work what? what are you trying todo? read/write? did you validated that the ACL has changed (using getacl)?

Comment: I'm trying to "write" . It seems that the ACL was not updated. However I didn't get any error either on update request ./gsutil setacl acl.txt gs://description
Setting ACL on gs://description/...

Comment: The issue was that I placed my policy block after the </Entries> tag so now I corrected it and works. I'm marking your answer accepted.

Comment: Worked great - the incantation I used was: "gsutil chacl -u myappid@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:FC gs://mybucket"

Answer (score 2):

Here's my answer from a similar question yesterday - The advantage here is that it will be easier to access other developer APIs that use the team configured in the developer console with the App Engine application.

You can use a google group to make this work for your custom domain.

In the cpanel for managing your domain go to the 'groups' tab and add a new group that will be for your app.
Add the service account *.gserviceaccount.com as a member to the group that you have created.
Add the group to the team for your project at https://code.google.com/apis/console.

Comment: Have you (or anyone else) actually gotten this to work to allow a GoogleApps domain to access Cloud Storage?  I just tried this and it doesn't seem to make a difference, I still get "Application Error: 8"

Comment: yes i have. you might want to use gsutil setacl if using the developers console to add to your team is not working for you.

Comment: Ah, you know, now it works for me, too.  Maybe took a moment for the permissions to propagate or something.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other solutions posted, if you create a new project using a gmail.com account, you can add Apps accounts as owners of the project, and even delete the original gmail account, while still preserving the ability to add any account to the project.

Comment: thanks Nick , that sounds like a great workaround but I still think the Google Apps issue should be fixed.